# How can i execute this bash script at logout?

Tags: bash

My problem is I need to convert this script bellow into an application, or find an easy way to have it executed at logout
i am new at scripting is there an application that can create a plist out of this bash script?
at the moment i am using ARD to push it to client machine but this is the long way
or can i just add this line (rm -rf /Users/!(admin|Shared) somewhere in system library?

```
#!/bin/bash  
shopt -s extglob   
rm -rf /Users/!(admin|Shared)
```

Comment: Put it in `~/.bash_logout`.

Comment: where can i find ~/.bash_logout

Comment: `~` is your home directory. (E.g.  `/Users/Kayman` depending on your username.)

Comment: when i type in terminal ~/.bash_logout i get No such file or directory!

Comment: It doesn't exist by default; you can create it.

Answer (score 1):

Put your script in `~/.bash_logout`

Then you can edit it:

```
vim ~/.bash_logout
```

Comment: when i type in terminal ~/.bash_logout i get No such file or directory!

Comment: @KaymanMacman Create it then. `vim ~/.bash_logout` just like it says in the answer.

Comment: @KaymanMacman it's really simple just type `vim ~/.bash_logout` and see what happened

Comment: ok this is what i get   ~                                                                               
"~/.bash_logout" [New File]

Comment: Ok, I guess you're not familar with `vim` editor. Please check that link, to learn basic edit commands: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/vim-for-beginners--cms-21118

Comment: Or use `echo "rm -rf /Users/something_smarter" >> ~/.bash_logout` if you do not want to learn vi yet. The rm command should be changed!

Comment: hi do i put all the script or just the last line: rm -rf /Users/!(admin|Shared)

Comment: cool guys thanks for all your help i manage to learn bit of VIM and created the two files with my scrip in it, but won't execute at logout, do i need to do any thing in terminal to execute these two files .bash_logout & .logout